# Problems with accessing SE sites with Opera VPN

Tags: bug, status-declined

The [Opera browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) recently introduced [a VPN feature](http://www.opera.com/blogs/desktop/2016/04/free-vpn-integrated-opera-for-windows-mac/).

When turned on, it tunnels traffic through their ([Opera Software's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Software)) proxy.

When opening Stack Exchange pages like

```
http://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-is-doing
```

I get

```
 Page Not Found
We couldn't find the page you requested. But we haven't looked inside your computer for it. Yet.
```

Those pages work in direct connection as usual.

I can see the Stack Exchange page, but not the content.

[image]

I've checked the network response, and it seems that the proxy responds with 404 on `http` version of URL is reached.

When I try the same URL with `https` it works. So I assume it's a problem with Opera.

Comment: I can see you are logged in from the screenshot, what I don't see is what the URL is (assuming it is the same as what you posted?). That would most likely mean that the VPN/Opera is mangling the URL when issuing the request to our servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our sites work well on most VPN solutions.

We can't fix a broken VPN solution.

What you are describing is the VPN completely blocking access to our site - there is nothing we can do to change it.

I suggest reporting this to Opera so they can fix the issue.

Comment: Its not typical proxy level blocking i think because i can see SU header and picture. Just to be clear i edited the question.

Comment: They might be rewriting URLs, making them invalid. Or messing around with cookies. Again - something they need to fix.